# Split the String into a list of values to use along 'IN' operator in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string `' 123', '6399', '  12', '   1'`. In the string there are sub strings with a single quote having spaces and number, both spaces and numbers are to be preserved. The sub string will be of max length 4, and if the length is not 4 there will be equal number of spaces added in sub string like if the value is 12 then there will be 2 spaces like this '  12' but if the value is 123 there will be only one space like this ' 123'.

I need to split this string and give it as input to 'IN' operator but if I have a sub string with single quotes in it, it is not working but single quotes are important for me to understand which sub string has how many spaces.

Comment: Have you try [string_split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: what version of sql-server, this is important because you may need a user defined function if string_split isn't available

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 approaches, the first should work in any version of SQL Server that supports CTEs and it avoids creating a user defined function. The second variant works with an inbuilt function `string_split` introduced in SQL Server 2016. NB: I have assumed you want to retain the leading spaces.

```
DECLARE @string varchar(4000) = ''' 123'', ''6399'', ''  12'', ''   1''';
DECLARE @separator varchar(10) = ',';

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        0 AS start,
        CHARINDEX(@separator, @string) AS [end]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        [end] + LEN(@separator),
        CHARINDEX(@separator, @string, [end] + LEN(@separator))
    FROM cte
    WHERE [end] > 0
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING(
            @string,
            start + CASE WHEN start > 0 THEN LEN(@separator) ELSE 0 END,
            CASE WHEN [end] > 0 THEN [end] - start - LEN(@separator) ELSE LEN(@string) - start END
        ) AS value
    FROM cte
)
SELECT
      REPLACE(value, '''', '') AS value 
    , LEN(REPLACE(value, '''', '')) AS value_len
FROM cte2;
```

| value | value_len |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 4 |
| 6399 | 4 |
| 12 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |

```
DECLARE @string varchar(4000) = ''' 123'', ''6399'', ''  12'', ''   1''';
DECLARE @separator varchar(10) = ',';

SELECT 
      RIGHT(REPLACE(value, '''', ''),4) AS value 
    , LEN(RIGHT(REPLACE(value, '''', ''),4)) AS value_len
FROM string_split(@string,@separator)
```

| value | value_len |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 4 |
| 6399 | 4 |
| 12 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h4V5lRhb)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom split function as follows

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[addSpaces](@data NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @s = REPLICATE( ' ' , 4-LEN(@data) )+@data
    RETURN(@s)
END

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit](@data NVARCHAR(MAX), @delimiter NVARCHAR(5))
RETURNS @t TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), data NVARCHAR(max), descriptor varchar(255) NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @textXML XML;
    SELECT    @textXML = CAST('<d>' + REPLACE(@data, @delimiter, '</d><d>') + '</d>' AS XML);
 
    INSERT INTO @t(data)
    SELECT  RTRIM(LTRIM(T.split.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'))) AS data
    FROM    @textXML.nodes('/d') T(split)
 
    RETURN
END
```

Usage

```
DECLARE @string as varchar(4000) = '''123'', ''6399'', ''  12'', ''   1''';
DECLARE @separator as varchar(10) = ',';

DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Val VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES(' 123')
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES('6399')
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES('  12')
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES('   4')
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES('   5')

SELECT * FROM @TABLE 
WHERE Val IN (
  SELECT [dbo].[addSpaces](REPLACE(data,'''','')) 
  FROM [dbo].[fnSplit](@string,',')
)
```

[image]

fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/9E1dWtMy
references: 
https://blog.nitinsawant.com/2014/10/how-to-find-common-words-between-two.html
https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/25/sql-server-repeate-string-n-times-using-string-function-replicate/